# Get length of hash without the empty values

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

```
filters = {
  "start_year" => "2009",
  "end_year" => "2011",
  "theme" => "",
  "discipline" => ""
}
```

`filters.length` is `4`, but I want to get `2` (the ones who have not only a key, but also a value)

Comment: It is neither valid Ruby object nor valid JSON object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
filters = {"start_year"=>"2009", "end_year"=>"2011", "theme"=>"", "discipline"=>""}

filters.count { |k, v| v.present? }
#=> 2
```

Comment: Where does `filters` come from?

Comment: @sawa added my assumption

Comment: thanks! it was indeed a ruby hash ;)

Comment: @PaulH I've edited your question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
filters.reject { |k, v| v.empty? }.length # => 2
```

Comment: Where does `filters` come from?

Comment: From the question :). "`filters.length` is gonna be 4, ...".

Comment: I wonder how that description in the question makes sense.

Comment: It would make sense if you assumed a valid hash given he (somehow) got an answer (4).

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json string.

```
require 'json'

json_string = <<EOS
{
  "filters": {
    "start_year": "2009",
    "end_year": "2011",
    "theme": "",
    "discipline": ""
  }
}
EOS

h = JSON.parse(json_string)
```

And filter values using `Enumerable#select`:

```
h['filters'].values.select { |x| x != "" }
# => ["2009", "2011"]
h['filters'].values.select { |x| x != "" }.size
# => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filters.values.reject(&:empty?).length
```

If you save empty values as `nil` rather than `''` you could use:

```
filters.values.compact.length
```